How to control INSERT size in Trino
I am using Trino 434 to read data from Hive connector and write it to Clickhouse. Turns out that Trino is doing lots of small inserts into Clickhouse (1.5k rows, ~1MB per insert).
Data itself is partitioned by minute, and each minute has ~500MB of data spread across files ~8-10MB each.
Is there any way to effectively coalesce data when doing INSERTs (similar to how you can instruct Spark to coalesce partitions)

To coalesce or batch inserts, you should look into the async_insert setting here:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings#async-insert
When setting async_insert =1, the data is batched in a buffer and inserted when the insert limit of the buffer is reached or the timeout exceeded.
Here is an additional article on the usage of this setting that describes the process in detail:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/asynchronous-inserts

I'm trying to achieve the batching at Trino side. For example, if Trino does 10 insert queries each inserting 2K rows, I want be able to make that trino does 2 queries inserting 10K rows each

Gotcha! Not sure how to batch on the Trino side!

write.batch-size ?
https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/clickhouse.html#general-configuration-properties

@gingerwizard
Tried write.batch-size today. It is. In Clickhouse connector page its description is confusing because it referring to statement, not the actual row count.
Additionally, this parameter "losly" controls the row per one insert. For instance, we see inserts of 12K rows when configured to 10K.
